# Use AWS Glue script to Ingest data into DB2 from S3 buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, db2, database-connection, aws-glue

I could successfully write and execute a Glue Job to bring data from DB2 into S3 buckets. But, can I do the opposite?

Write data into DB2 table by pulling data from S3 buckets (parquet Files)?

Comment: Yes, this should be possible so long as you have your targets defined (S3 and JDBC connections). In fact, with a Data Catalog pointing at the S3 location, you won't event need to do the conversion from Parquet format, you should have it available to you in a dataframe that you can then store as rows in your DB2 database table.

Comment: @Norman I could not find any documentation expanding on what you just said, can you point me to any?

Comment: No specific guidance, but Glue supports this bidirectional relationship. I found this article, hopefully it's helpful: https://medium.com/codefully-io/aws-glue-for-loading-data-from-a-file-to-the-database-extract-transform-load-fe6b722e11b8

Comment: Hi @ramyav can you please describe how you can write and execute a Glue Job to bring data from DB2 into S3 buckets. i am in the same situation but i am new to aws glue. Can you help me on this